# How to use CGColorCreate to get white with Swift in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, cgcolor

Maybe I'm misinterpreting the information out there but in my code I have:

```
let color = CGColorCreate(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
```

Which compiles fine but the text is always black no matter what I set the values to. What should the line look like to get white text?

Comment: How do you use this color for text output?

Comment: I use it in a Graphics Context:
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color)

Comment: How, exactly, are you drawing the text?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing out the opacity of the colour space. I was able to get a bright, light orange with opacity with this `[1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.2]`. The opacity of the colour is `0.2` in my example.

```
let colour = CGColorCreate(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), [1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.2])
```

Set the opacity to `1` for a solid colour.

`colour?` I'm British old boy!

**EDIT:** Opps, I think I answered to the wrong question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your lighting? Try to add the following:

```
scnView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem when trying to draw text onto an image. I now found out that at least on iOS 8

```
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, CGColorCreate(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]))
```

doesn't really do anything. To set the color of the text, I rather had to add an attribute to the Dictionary that is in the `withFont` parameter of

```
    text.drawInRect(rectText, withFont: font)
```

#### Example:

Assuming we already have an UIImage `image`

```
    let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 18)
    let text: NSString = "String to draw"
    let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: rect.width, height: rect.height), true, 0)
    image.drawInRect(rect)
    let attr: NSDictionary = [NSFontAttributeName : font!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor() ]
    let size = text.sizeWithAttributes(attr)
    let rectText = CGRectMake(image.size.width-size.width, image.size.height-(size.height+4), image.size.width-(size.width+4), image.size.height)
    text.drawInRect(rectText, withAttributes: attr)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This example borrows heavily from the blog post at http://www.bytearray.org/?p=5416.